# Why do i get "uselpffregexps is undefined"-error in FireBug, while debugging AJAX Control Toolki enabled website

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i'm getting the error stated in question title, when i'm debugging a site where i use MS AJAX Control Toolkit aspx-controls?

Anyone have any idea that where is this error coming from? Google didn't find a single hit, so i don't have a starting point for fixing this problem.

Here is the output from FireBug:

```
uselpffregexps is undefined
Sys$CultureInfo$_getAbbrMonthIndex("")ScriptRe...=6a8eb360 (line 6391)
ScriptResource.axd?d=sa7ZMv6_yzLhyiR7nmDfMyrmw3A1tuch8SygUPxmarMgXuxDwB9112XyZgfam1WcY77sgif7Jo4KV2D_tr1V4A2&t=4899f375()()ScriptRe...=4899f375 (line 1)
this._upperAbbrMonths =  this...s.dateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames);
```

That webresource is the one that the Toolkit adds on to the page automatically. The actual error seems to point towards the known bug in Ajax Toolkit's Common.js. Toolkit is the latest version available (may 2009 release).

I'll be happy to provide additional information!

greets,
J. Arola

Comment: Okay, problem is in a FireFox plugin called LastPass. If i disable it, then the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, i previously forgot to create the actual answer for this.

If LastPass-addon is installed in FireFox and you use FireBug to debug an AJAX Control Toolkit enabled site, then you'll apparently get the "uselpffregexps is undefined"-error.

The "uselpffregexps is undefined"-error doesn't seem to have any real effect, so it's merely an annoyance.

If someone has encountered this and can confirm, i'd appreciate it!